# Reshaping the layout of data

Tags: formatting, stata

I am trying to re-organise my data, but am struggling to work out how.

Currently it is organised like this:

```
Person  total   Birmingham  London  Coventry    Edinburgh
James   6           1                   5   
Kitty   9           2         3         1           3
Heather 3                     2                     1
John    5                     2         2           1
```

And I want to reorganise it to look like this:

```
Person   Place      Visits
James    total       6
James    Birmingham  1
James    London      0
James    Coventry    5
James    Edinburgh   0
Kitty    total       9
Kitty    Birmingham  2
Kitty    London      3
Kitty    Coventry    1
Kitty    Edinburgh   3
Heather  total       3
Heather  Birmingham  0
Heather  London      2
Heather  Coventry    0
Heather  Edinburgh   1
John     total       5
John     Birmingham  0
John     London      2
John     Coventry    2
John     Edinburgh   1
```

I've tried using the Stata command `reshape` but haven't got very far with it.

I believe my main issue is that I have lots of variables which are all unique names. Rather than listing them all within the `reshape` command, is there another way?

I haven't been able to find any help threads elsewhere (maybe as I'm not sure how to describe the problem).

I'm also sure there are ways to do this in Excel, but I am attempting to keep all my analysis in one place (Stata).

Comment: You should always indicate the code you tried.

Comment: Note that `reshape` never expects a list of variable names, but of variable stubs.

Comment: `search reshape` in Stata points to many resources. In particular, http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/ explains your main problem, which is needing a `rename` first. It's always best to look at Stata documentation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to prefix the variables you want to reshape. You can do it automatically, e.g., like this:

```
ds Person, not
rename (`r(varlist)') (Visits=)
```

Then `reshape` should be straightforward:

```
reshape long Visits, i(Person) j(Place) string
```

Comment: thanks- this looks exactly like what I am after.
One question, it's not liking the "rename....." line as it is saying the parentheses are unbalanced. I can't see why that would be though

Comment: Funny. Did you execute rename immediately after ds? Otherwise the r(varlist) could have been cleared by some other command.

Comment: Just reran my code from the top and it worked- not sure what was going wrong previously.
Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My advice is similar in spirit to that of @Andrei, but with an important difference in detail.

In essence, you shouldn't treat the `total` variable as similar to the others, as it is not. Otherwise analyses downstream may be more complicated than necessary or even quite wrong.

```
clear 
input str7 Person  total   Birmingham  London  Coventry    Edinburgh
"James"   6           1         .          5          .
"Kitty"   9           2         3         1           3
"Heather" 3           .          2         .            1
"John"    5           .         2         2           1
end 
rename (Birmingham-Edinburgh) (Visits=) 
reshape long Visits, i(Person) string j(Place) 
list, sepby(Person) 

     +---------------------------------------+
     |  Person        Place   total   Visits |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. | Heather   Birmingham       3        . |
  2. | Heather     Coventry       3        . |
  3. | Heather    Edinburgh       3        1 |
  4. | Heather       London       3        2 |
     |---------------------------------------|
  5. |   James   Birmingham       6        1 |
  6. |   James     Coventry       6        5 |
  7. |   James    Edinburgh       6        . |
  8. |   James       London       6        . |
     |---------------------------------------|
  9. |    John   Birmingham       5        . |
 10. |    John     Coventry       5        2 |
 11. |    John    Edinburgh       5        1 |
 12. |    John       London       5        2 |
     |---------------------------------------|
 13. |   Kitty   Birmingham       9        2 |
 14. |   Kitty     Coventry       9        1 |
 15. |   Kitty    Edinburgh       9        3 |
 16. |   Kitty       London       9        3 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```